# Alternatives to bruteforce KeePass Cracker

Tags: windows, brute-force, password-cracking, keepass

Recently I have been working on a little project. I have been able to crack my [keePass](http://keepass.info/) .kdbx file by running a simple brute force attack with the [KeePass Cracker](http://keecracker.mbw.name/) and a custom made word list.

This is to easy. Lets say I didn't know my own password at all. Is there any other method I could approach?

If I didn't know my own password I would use a couple of word lists and hope that I get it right but is there perhaps another method more efficient in nature. Obviously social engineering is out the window.

I am exclusively using windows for this project but a Linux method will be appreciated so don't be shy.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

> KeePass Cracker Example

```
KeeCracker.exe -w C:\KeeCracker\List\Word.txt C:\KeeCracker\Topsecretpasswords.kdbx
```

Comment: There _shouldn't_ be a more efficient method - if there is, it's a flaw with the system! The only efficiencies you should be able to make are picking the brute force order, so trying dictionary words and combinations which make sentences before random 30 character strings, but you'd need more information to be able to optimise for those.

Comment: If there was a publicly known easier way, why would you use the software?

Answer (score 1):

With no knowledge of password selection psychology, your options are limited. The only obvious improvement that I see is to increase attack speed by switching platforms.

Looking at the source code of KeePass Cracker, it is CPU only. You should get a lot more speed by switching to a cracker with GPU support, such as hashcat (which runs on both Windows and Linux, and supports KeePass as a target hash type).